# Wifi Direct discovery

Tags: android, ios, wifi-direct

I am just getting started with wifi direct.  I know that wifi direct works by discovering devices and services.  My question is: if I have my wifi enabled on my smartphone and I am not running an application that uses wifi direct, is my phone still discoverable to a phone that is running wifi direct device discovery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to establish a WiFi Direct connection both phones should be running WiFi Direct discovery. In other words, they will see each other when they are both scanning for WiFi direct connections at the same time. This is because the way WiFi Direct works is that when phones are scanning for WiFi Direct connections, they will negotiate with the other peers for the role of Access Point or Slave device. However, when phone A is connected to phone B via WiFi Direct and phone C is scanning for connections, it will detect the connection of A-B since one of them is acting as an Access point.

Answer (score 1):

I will add some point on @Ziad answer. During scan process, one device who started scanning will broadcast 802.11 WiFi Direct probe request and another device will listen to that probe request and send back the probe response, that how they will discover each other. 
Scanning will happen on one channel 1, 6 ,11 on 2.4 GHz.